# Javascript Ajax put open() and send() after onreadystatechange()

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I saw some code on w3schools using Ajax in javascript

[Asynchronous request](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_first)

[Synchronous request](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_asyncfalse)

I want to ask, why in the asynchronous request method, it puts open() and send() after xhttp.onreadystatechange?

I think it is logical to specify the request (open method) and send the request (send method), then change the .innerHTML to xhttp.responseText? Why they change the .innerHTML first before sending request in the code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: In short: That's how AJAX works. There should be plenty of resource on the internet explaining in detail about how it works

Comment: The `innerHTML` is not changed before `send` and `open`. That’s inside a function that will be called later.

Comment: @Xufox Yep, that's how AJAX works. `xhttp.onreadystatechange = function()` didn't actually executed until `send()` is finished executing